# Getting ORA error while upserting pricebook entry records in Scratch org

Tags: managed-package

I am getting an error in my scracth org while upserting pricebookentry records from a batch. Following is an error message:

> 2:56:27.0 (361038337)|SYSTEM_MODE_EXIT|false 02:56:27.0
>   (361091161)|FATAL_ERROR|System.DmlException: Upsert failed. First
>   exception on row 0 with id 01u2D0000022WEFQA2; first error:
>   UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION, common.exception.SqlNoDataFoundException:
>   ORA-01403: no data found ORA-06512: at "DOC.CPRODUCTACCESS", line 950
>   ORA-06512: at "DOC.CACCESS", line 2998 ORA-06512: at "DOC.CACCESS",
>   line 2827 ORA-06512: at line 1
>
> SQLException while executing plsql statement: {call
>   cAccess.check_entity_access_proc_ncu(?,?,?,?,?,?)}(EXCLUDED, EXCLUDED,
>   01u2D0000022WEF, EXCLUDED, true, false): []

I have the Admin User profile and have access to all the pricebookentry and product fields.
Following is the code snippet I am using to insert pricebookentries :

```
currencyPricebookId = 'Some Pricebook Id';
for(PricebookEntry pricebookEntry: PiceBookEntryList){
    String key = String.valueOf(pricebookEntry.Pricebook2Id) + String.valueOf(pricebookEntry.Product2Id);
    priceBookEntryMap.put(key, pricebookEntry);
}       
for(Product2 product2: currencyProducts){
    if(!productIdVsPricebookentry.containsKey(product2.id)){
        PricebookEntry standardPBE = priceBookEntryMap.get(String.valueOf(standardPB.ID) + String.valueOf(product2.Id));
        productIdVsPricebookentry.put(product2.id,standardPBE);
        if(standardPBE == null){
            standardPBE = new PricebookEntry(
                                                    Pricebook2Id = standardPB.ID, 
                                                    Product2Id = product2.Id, 
                                                    IsActive = true, 
                                                    UnitPrice = 0.0,
                                                    UseStandardPrice = false
                                                    );
            productIdVsPricebookentry.put(product2.id,standardPBE);
            standardPriceBookEntryList.add(standardPBE);
        }
    }
    PricebookEntry pbe = priceBookEntryMap.get(String.valueOf(currencyPricebookId) + String.valueOf(product2.Id));
    if(pbe == null) {
        pbe = new PricebookEntry(
                                Pricebook2Id = currencyPricebookId, 
                                Product2Id = product2.Id, 
                                IsActive = true, 
                                UnitPrice = 0.0,
                                UseStandardPrice = false
        );
        PiceBookEntryList.add(pbe);
    }
}
upsert standardPriceBookEntryList;
upsert PiceBookEntryList;
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is a low-level error. You'll need to contact support. If you even want to have a hope of us debugging this, you'll need to include your trigger code, which you can [edit] in to your question.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks. I have edited my question to include code snippet. I am getting this error in the last line of code while upserting pricebookentries.